# C# unable to return json object of large data?

Tags: javascript, c#, json

Using C# MVC ASP.NET:

hello, im trying to pass data from my controller to the view to display on a browser.

below is the data from my local SQL database that i want to return to show

MapController.cs

```
// Gets Traffic Speed Band data from database and returns as JSON object
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetSpeedBands()
        {
            //Creating List
            List<DataLibrary.Models.TrafficSpeedBandsModel> data1 = TrafficSpeedBandsProcessor.LoadTrafficSpeedBands();
            //List<DataLibrary.Models.BusStopsModel> data2 = BusStopsProcessor.LoadBusStops();

            //return list as Json
            return Json(data1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

View.cshtml

```
function ReadSpeedBands() {

            $.getJSON("/Map/GetSpeedBands",
                function (json) {                    
                    redlatlngs.push([1.3805895432850994, 103.74201730473243], [1.3800400299576012, 103.74120855605975]);
                    var polyline = L.polyline(redlatlngs, { color: 'red', opacity: 1, weight: 5 }).addTo(map);
                    ColorCodeSpeedBands(json);

                }
            );
}
```

the data that i wanna return is `data1` but it is not showing on the map. i tested with another line of code which is `data2` and it works. (basically, the red polyline shows up on the map when using `data2` but not when using `data1`. I am able to `writeline` both `data1` and `data2` to console, so nothing is wrong with the data itself. that leaves the culprit to the return Json function)

so how come `data1` is unable to work?

`fyi`, `data1` contains a list of 58000 records,
`whereas` `data2` contains a list of 5000+ records

is it becuz the Json function can't return a large amount of data?

any help is appreciated!

Comment: "that leaves the culprit to the return json function" - or whatever is actually using the JSON. I suggest you add more diagnostics to whatever is consuming the JSON so you can see what's happening on the client side.

Comment: It's likely that you have exceeded the max request length. Check this question for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded

Comment: @Sami the question you shared is about request parameters not reply sizes. It could be but not in this case

Comment: i have played around abit, and the maximum records i can fetch is 9629 out of 58000 records. any more than that, my map would not show the data. im still not sure how to add diagnostics

Comment: Try setting the max request length key in web.config to maximum int value.

Comment: still doesnt work. once i changed it to select 9630, the polylines wont show up

Comment: Did you also set maxAllowedContentLength?

Comment: yes i set everything that is listed on the other post. but didnt work. in the end, i made a few loops that retrieves it bit by bit as opposed to returning the whole 58k records